# Font Size of Tabs and its content

Tags: visualforce, tab, tabpanel

How to increase the fontsize of the tab and its content.Currently it is smaller than regular.

**Update** :How to make tabs curved?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="true">
<!-- Define Tab panel .css styles -->
<style>
.activeTab {background-color: #236FBD; color:white; background-image:none}
.inactiveTab { background-color: lightgrey; color:black; background-image:none}
</style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery.noConflict();
</script>       
<!-- Create Tab panel -->
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" id="AccountTabPanel"
    tabClass='activeTab' inactiveTabClass='inactiveTab'>
    <apex:tab label="One" name="name1" id="tabOne">content for tab one</apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="Two" name="name2" id="tabTwo">content for tab two</apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should increase the font size:font-size:250%;

Refer:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp

Usage:

```
.activeTab {background-color: #236FBD; color:white; background-image:none;**font-size:250%;**}
```

For content size use contentstyle in the

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_tabPanel.htm

contentStyle="font-size: 32px;"

```
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" id="AccountTabPanel"
    tabClass='activeTab' inactiveTabClass='inactiveTab' contentStyle="font-size: 32px;">
```

you should be seeing something like this:

[image]

**UPDATE: ROUNDED CORNERS ( Is this what you are looking for?)**

**code :** 
I assume Salesforce uses curvy corners (jquery plugin) for tabpanel after reading through this link I was able to get an idea on rounding the corners.

`border-radius:20px;` rounds the border. The challenge was it had a image background that was drawing an extra line next to the border. To get rid of the extra lines and give it a smooth finish you need to adjust some properties mentioned in the below link
https://community.jboss.org/thread/164445?tstart=0

```
.activeTab {background-color: lightgrey; color:black; background-image:none;font-size:160%;border-radius:20px;}
.inactiveTab {background-color: lightgrey; color:black; background-image:none;font-size:160%;border-radius:20px;}
.rich-tabhdr-side-border { background-image: none; }
.rich-tabhdr-side-cell { border-top: none; }
```

[image]

Comment: but the content in it is smaller..How to increase the content size

Comment: How to make tabs as curved ?

Comment: @sf.dev Can you post this as a different question . I am poor with CSS but I did figure out a solution. It would help many who might be looking for answer on how to round the tab panel. I will post my answer in your new question merely to make it useful to others looking for it.

Comment: Rao, just a minor note. Please consider not linking to w3schools ;) http://www.w3fools.com/ & http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120621/w3fools-alternatives - bit harsh, I used it a lot myself in the past... but worth pointing out that sometimes the poor quality code you'll learn to write outweighs the easy to understand examples they provide.

Comment: @eyescream valid point. I always felt w3's online try it feature was such an eye candy so include the link so that the user can understand better.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ all the way! you can link to quick examples proving what you're trying to show, can include jQuery and whatnot... Well, it won't run Visualforce code but still :P http://jsfiddle.net/V92Gn/ or http://jsfiddle.net/jbristowe/LCtCg/ - you won't make it at W3S ;)

Comment: @sf.dev update the code for rounded tab panel :)

Answer (score 3):

try for the content:

```
<style>
.rich-tabpanel-content {font-size:200%}
</style>
```

And add `font-size` on the `.activeTab` class